# using an expression to show or hide rectangle based on a parameter value (SSRS)

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, parameters, type-conversion

Trying to show/hide a couple of rectangles in SSRS based on an expression which uses the value of a parameter in the report. See the screenshots for more details. When the '-Cover pages' label is picked I want it to display the rectangle but I consistently get the following errors. It can't seem to convert and read the parameter expression no matter what I do.

The expression I'm trying to use is:

```
=iif(Parameters!specparam.Value="-Cover Pages",true,false)
```

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the label of your parameter is what you're looking for based on the image provided and your expression. Try to switch instead to:

```
=IIF(Parameters!specparam.Label="-Cover Pages",TRUE,FALSE)
```

(Note: I switched `specparam.Value` to `specparam.Label`.

Comment: Ya, I've switched that and should have updated my original post, however it didn't matter the conversion still didn't work. What did work was using =iif(Parameters!specparam.label.Equals("-Cover Pages"),true,false). Now the only issue is that the rectangle still shows even if "-Cover Pages" isn't selected in the parameter options. Trying to find a way to have it not show the cover pages if that option isn't select

Answer (score 0):

Your comment is very close. Apply this expression to the `Hidden` property of the rectangle:

```
=IIF( Parameters!specparam.Label.Equals("-Cover Pages"), FALSE, TRUE )
```

You'll notice I have switched around the `FALSE` and `TRUE` as you **don't** want the rectangle to hide when the parameter matches.

**Edit:** 
As you're dealing with a multivalue parameter, you can use a combination of `Array.IndexOf` and `Split` to check if your value is one of the selected parameters.
Apply this expression to the `Hidden` property of your rectangle:

```
=IIF( Array.IndexOf( Split( Parameters!specparam.Value, "," ), "-Cover Pages" ) > -1, FALSE, TRUE )
```

Comment: This is essentially what I did though I had to create a separate parameter to get it to work. The first parameter I was using had lots of items in it and for whatever reason SSRS would not respond appropriately. Maybe it's because with that parameter you can select multiple items to view? Not sure but either way it either always show the rectangle or never showed it. I had to create a second variable which let you select either yes or no, which worked.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise your parameter was multi-value. I've edited my answer to provide you another possible solution without the need for the extra parameter. Glad you got it sorted :)